# opencv IplImage sign

Tags: opencv, unsigned, signed, iplimage

I created IPL Image class instance like a following thing.

```
temp[0] = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

and I use it like this.

```
temp[0]->imageData[y*temp[0]->widthStep + x] = nHistValue;
```

So it should be type of unsigned char.. but

when I debug..

It was changed type of char..

what's wrong??

I am going to attach an images..
but I need more reputation things to do.. so.. I cannot

Comment: oh, please stay away from the outdated c-api. they switched to c++ 5 years ago, you should not write any code like this now.

Comment: do you get wrong results or is your problem just what the debugger displays?

Comment: Thank you ! I changed all IplImage to Mat!! Than problem was soloved